# npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.'

Tags: github, npm, npm-publish

Im trying to do npm publish from powershell to my organization github package, with a specific package name but im getting this error below with only specific name when i change the name im able to publish successfully, i have restrictions to not change the package name because other projects have dependencies with this name

npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/myorg%package-name - Permission permission_denied: write_package
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.

im part of the github organization, tried to replace tokens also but nothing is working because of the specific name , and that name is not available in packages anywhere in my organization